# How to create SampleDataSource for GridApp template using images that stored at PicturesLibrary?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am trying to create DataSource for GridApp. I get images from PicturesLibrary using GetFilesAsync(). I modified SampleDataSource.cs: in data structure I use StorageFile imagePath instead of string imagePath. And of course I wrote a code that creates BitmapImage from StorageFile using IRandomAccessStream instead of creation BitmapImage from Uri.

So this code can be compiled but it doesn't work. Here the reasons of it:
async method GetFilesAsync() not blocks the main thread. And GroupedItemsPage.xaml.cs asks SampleDataSource before GetFilesAsync() provides necessary information. This cause an exception TypeInitializationException.

The obvious solution is to use sync analog of GetFilesAsync(). But there are some new problems:

1. It seems that it's impossible to get files from KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary synchronously.
2. It's whole bad idea, because if I have a big amount of pictures then generation of GroupedItemsPage will cause seriously freezing.

So, how can I solve this problem? I am asking only conception of solution. How I should organize the architecture of my App?